# JQuery DataTables Not Fully Working Correctly with ASP.NET GridView Paging (only searches current page)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatables

I have an ASP.NET GridView with the following setup:

- Sorting is implemented using ASP.NET GridView's Sorting (OnSorting="gridList_Sorting")
- Paging is implemented using ASP.NET GridView's Paging (OnPageIndexChanging="gridList_PageIndexChanging")
- Searching/Filtering is implemented using JQuery DataTables

Background: The setup is that way because the GridView needs to be editable. I tried implementing sorting, paging, and searching/filtering exclusively using DataTables but I get the issue of the row-being-edited jumping unpredictably within the GridView (the row's position changes when it's clicked to be edited), and I wasn't able to solve it.

Going back, **the issue is DataTables is only able to filter if the record occurs in the current GridView page**. Example: In the [edited image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQhTT.png), searching for "Fiona Green" will not display the filtered results. However, searching for "Hope" will display the filtered results. [Please see here for the code snippet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIAaN.png)

Due to a tight time constraint, I need to maintain the setup (sorting and paging is done by ASP.NET GridView while searching/filtering is done by JQuery DataTables). I hope someone can help advise on troubleshooting and solving this issue. Advanced thanks!!!

Comment: I think we need to see some code here.  Sounds like you're only searching a "view model" instead of a database.  The query is still done in ASP.NET.  jQuery is client-side.

Comment: Thanks for replying, pcalkins! I updated the post with the code. Yes, you're right, my JQuery DataTables is configured to operate on client-side only. Sigh, that means is that the ASP.NET GridView is only returning results for the current page versus ASP.NET GridView returning all results then paging it at client-side : ( By any chance, have you tried applying ServerSideProcessing in JQuery DataTables but retain ASP.NET GridView paging? I wonder if it'll conflict.

Comment: Your search should post the search term to the asp.net page, then you can process and return results to jQuery so that it can process client side in a callback.  (You should really post your code as text instead of as a screenshot...)  I haven't used gridview in a web context so I don't have any specific advice other than that the datatable can be sent back to your client-side callback as json and should convert pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Will try it. If you have sample JQuery Datatables code on implementing the search callback, that would really help. P.S. Will post code as text next time :)

Comment: I took a quick look at some docs... I would try setting "bDestroy" to false... assuming that jQuery has the entire datatable already, it's possible this would fix it.